# How can ballet dancers deal with ingrown toenails?

Tags: pain, feet, ballet

I am suffering from ingrown toenails as a result of fairly recent and constant ballet dance routines. I got them cut back at a chiropodist but it still hurts. What should I do ? Keep cutting them back  - or get them removed ?

Comment: Question asks for personal medical advice -- would have gone over better as "How can ballet dancers deal with ingrown toenails?"

Comment: @Noumenon - It's still personal medical advice no matter how you cast it.

Answer (score -1):

Commenters on [/r/ballet](http://www.reddit.com/r/BALLET/comments/14mrgy/dancers_what_do_you_do_to_reduce_ingrown_toenail/) said,

> do NOT cut them very short, they will just keep growing back. You have to let them grow to the point where they don't hurt as much and keep them at a length that doesn't bother you but isn't too long for pointe. You can also soak your feet in water and epsom salt, google it for how much. This helps heal your toes, especially if you've cut them short recently. I hope this helps, good luck!

There are several other comments there which I have not excerpted since I have no expertise in the matter.